# Opennebula on Ubuntu

Tags: rubygems, ubuntu-14.04, opennebula

I wish to install opennebula on my Ubuntu 14.04 . I am proceeding as per the manual provided by  Opennebula.org (http://docs.opennebula.org/pdf/4.6/opennebula_4.6_design_and_installation_guide.pdf, Pg 17 Para 1.3 Installing on Ubuntu/Debian). I have installed new JSON ruby library using the command "**$ sudo gem install json**" . But the next command "**$ sudo mv /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/json.rb /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/json.rb.no**" is showing the following error
"**mv: cannot stat ‘/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/json.rb’: No such file or directory**"
Can somebody please help me how to rectify this error. ?
PS : I am new to Linux World .Please try to keep it as simple as possible.

Comment: I followed this link for the latest Opennebula and it worked out great. Two hosts and shared storage virtual network plus LAN. I suggest this quick start: http://docs.opennebula.org/4.12/design_and_installation/quick_starts/qs_ubuntu_kvm.html

Answer (score -2):

Verifies that the directory /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/json.rb exists.

Execute

```
ls -l /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/json.rb
```

Most likely, the directory in question does not exist.

I advise you to search where you installed opennebula.

In your case you can locate where json.rb is doing

```
find / -name json.rb
```

With this command you will know in which directory is json.rb

NOTE:
If you want to post the result of

```
ls -l /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/json.rb
```

and

```
find / -name json.rb
```

To be able to help you step by step.